# Did I miss a step when I enabled my content type related feature?

Tags: 7, nodes, features

I have a Feature (with strong arm enabled) which I am using to save a content type.  The content only has two additional fields: field_company_search_terms and field_company_url_element, both of which are text fields.

- I created a Feature module that only contained this content type and related dependencies.
- I copied the feature module to a different site
- I enabled it on the Feature page

When I enabled it on a site, I got a huge error when I viewed the sites content list (shown below.)  Did I need to include another item in my feature or is there a step that I missed?>

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'internal_forms.field_data_field_status_calculated_weight' doesn't exist: SELECT t.* FROM {field_data_field_status_calculated_weight} t WHERE (entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (entity_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1, :db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4, :db_condition_placeholder_5, :db_condition_placeholder_6, :db_condition_placeholder_7, :db_condition_placeholder_8, :db_condition_placeholder_9, :db_condition_placeholder_10, :db_condition_placeholder_11, :db_condition_placeholder_12, :db_condition_placeholder_13, :db_condition_placeholder_14, :db_condition_placeholder_15, :db_condition_placeholder_16, :db_condition_placeholder_17, :db_condition_placeholder_18, :db_condition_placeholder_19, :db_condition_placeholder_20, :db_condition_placeholder_21, :db_condition_placeholder_22, :db_condition_placeholder_23, :db_condition_placeholder_24, :db_condition_placeholder_25, :db_condition_placeholder_26, :db_condition_placeholder_27, :db_condition_placeholder_28, :db_condition_placeholder_29, :db_condition_placeholder_30, :db_condition_placeholder_31, :db_condition_placeholder_32, :db_condition_placeholder_33, :db_condition_placeholder_34, :db_condition_placeholder_35, :db_condition_placeholder_36, :db_condition_placeholder_37, :db_condition_placeholder_38, :db_condition_placeholder_39, :db_condition_placeholder_40, :db_condition_placeholder_41, :db_condition_placeholder_42, :db_condition_placeholder_43, :db_condition_placeholder_44, :db_condition_placeholder_45, :db_condition_placeholder_46, :db_condition_placeholder_47, :db_condition_placeholder_48, :db_condition_placeholder_49, :db_condition_placeholder_50)) AND (language IN (:db_condition_placeholder_51)) AND (deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_52) ORDER BY delta ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 203 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 205 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => 206 [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => 321 [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => 323 [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => 324 [:db_condition_placeholder_7] => 327 [:db_condition_placeholder_8] => 332 [:db_condition_placeholder_9] => 333 [:db_condition_placeholder_10] => 343 [:db_condition_placeholder_11] => 385 [:db_condition_placeholder_12] => 386 [:db_condition_placeholder_13] => 392 [:db_condition_placeholder_14] => 406 [:db_condition_placeholder_15] => 433 [:db_condition_placeholder_16] => 434 [:db_condition_placeholder_17] => 435 [:db_condition_placeholder_18] => 436 [:db_condition_placeholder_19] => 441 [:db_condition_placeholder_20] => 505 [:db_condition_placeholder_21] => 510 [:db_condition_placeholder_22] => 512 [:db_condition_placeholder_23] => 539 [:db_condition_placeholder_24] => 554 [:db_condition_placeholder_25] => 572 [:db_condition_placeholder_26] => 584 [:db_condition_placeholder_27] => 586 [:db_condition_placeholder_28] => 588 [:db_condition_placeholder_29] => 592 [:db_condition_placeholder_30] => 593 [:db_condition_placeholder_31] => 647 [:db_condition_placeholder_32] => 663 [:db_condition_placeholder_33] => 682 [:db_condition_placeholder_34] => 683 [:db_condition_placeholder_35] => 684 [:db_condition_placeholder_36] => 688 [:db_condition_placeholder_37] => 724 [:db_condition_placeholder_38] => 733 [:db_condition_placeholder_39] => 735 [:db_condition_placeholder_40] => 793 [:db_condition_placeholder_41] => 868 [:db_condition_placeholder_42] => 908 [:db_condition_placeholder_43] => 909 [:db_condition_placeholder_44] => 919 [:db_condition_placeholder_45] => 920 [:db_condition_placeholder_46] => 921 [:db_condition_placeholder_47] => 922 [:db_condition_placeholder_48] => 939 [:db_condition_placeholder_49] => 984 [:db_condition_placeholder_50] => 987 [:db_condition_placeholder_51] => und [:db_condition_placeholder_52] => 0 ) in field_sql_storage_field_storage_load() (line 349 of C:\xampp\htdocs\forms\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).

Comment: Looks like calculated weight is provided by another module, correct? Perhaps this? https://drupal.org/project/computed_field

Comment: Yes, but that field is on a different content type.  Is there a chance that this feature overwrote that field definition?